# undefined method `where' for #<Enquiry:0x8c24070>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Im trying to create a dashboard table in ActiveAdmin for Enquiries received this year and counted by month.

Received an `undefined method 'where' for #<Enquiry:0x8c24070>` error for the code below.

```
 column do                           
    panel "Enquiries by month" do
      table_for Enquiry.where("created_at >= ?", Time.now.at_beginning_of_year) do
         column("January") {|t| t.where(t.created_at.strftime("%B") => 'January').count}
      end
    end
  end
```

I'm confused because similar queries worked well with other models, though this is the only query where I'm trying to group records by month `created_at`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to find `Enquiry` in one specific `Enquiry`, as I see from your error message.
Instead you need to find it in array like `Enquiry.all` or so on.

And can you show a code, where it works. In other models.

Comment: You're right, as for my other models, I used partials and hard coded it instead of using the activeadmin dashboard directly as i stupidly tried to do here. I blame sleep deprivation and lack of coffee =)

Comment: As for my Date based SQL queries, I just found the awesome [by_star gem](https://github.com/radar/by_star). Highly recommended.